# Path to use templateUrl in angular-material

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-material

I'm trying to use the modal prompt with angular-material. Because I want that my modal has a specific design, I'm trying to inject my HTML by using templateUrl.

Here is my code in mycontroller.js :

```js
 var prompt = this.mdDialog.prompt({
            templateUrl: require('../other/security.html'),
            clickOutsideToClose: 'true'
    });
```

My problem is that I always have the following exception when I try to open the modal :

```
Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: ./security.html
```

My architecture is the following :

```
+ ---- src
        + ---- app
            + ---- controllers
                  + ---- home
                        + ---- mycontroller.js
                  + ---- other
                        + ---- security.html
```

I have the impression that I try all the possible combinations but probably not...

Do you have any idea of what is the correct path to give to templateUrl ?

Any healp or idea would be great ! It's going to make me crazy.

Thanks a lot

EDIT : federico scamuzzi, do you mean "./src/app/controllers/other/security.html" ? No, I still have the same error.

Comment: i think you have to give the FULLPATH to templateUrl from your app folder

Answer (score 0):

can you try

`/src/app/controllers/other/security.html`

starting the address by root directory should work.

Comment: Remove 'require' just use place the address in ' ' without require.

Comment: Sorry, it still doesn't work... I always have the same error.